# How to write words and integers into arrays, line by line, from a file

Tags: c, arrays

I have a text file `text.txt` that contains the following data:

```
David 8 13
Bob 9 15
Dylan 3 18
Andy 4 14
```

I need to write the names to an array, and the other numbers to their own individual arrays as well. This will be used for processing later when I expand on the programs functionality.

I have a program that writes the entire file to a char array, this is a start but I am very stuck. I need the components of each line written to their own arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    char* string[100];
    char line[100];

    FILE *file; 
    file = fopen("text.txt", "r"); 

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) { // EDIT: I added a { here!
        printf("%s", line);
        string[i]=line;
        i++;
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<4; i++) {
        printf("\n%s", string[i]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

The current code outputs the following:

```
David 8 13
Bob 9 15
Dylan 3 18
Andy 4 14
```

Comment: First thing to do before anything else is to indent your code. OK someone has done it for you.

Comment: ...then look into the `sscanf` function. `strtok` may also be useful.

Comment: Hint: `string[i]=line;` does not copy the string, it just copies the pointer. Hint: look into `strdup`, or into `malloc` and `strcpy`. Read the chapter dealing with strings and with pointers in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Done by a kind observer! (Also made a 'typo' correction?)

Comment: BTW i would implement a control, if the access to the file was successful or not, like that:  `if(( file = fopen("text.txt"),"r") == 0) printf("Error on File opening"); else { the code if the file was open for read succesfully} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly you need 3 arrays: one for the names, one for the first integer value and one for the second integer value. I assume you have white characters (space, tab, new line) between the values, you can do the following (you don't have to read the whole line) (check out @Tal Avraham's aswer as well!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRINGS (10)
#define MAX_STRING_LEN (100)

int main()
{
    char names[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN] = { 0 };
    int firstValues[MAX_STRINGS] = { 0 };
    int secondValues[MAX_STRINGS] = { 0 };

    FILE* file = fopen("text.txt", "r"); // check if open was successful!

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS; ++i)
    {
        if (!fscanf(file, "%s", names[i])) //read the name as string
            break;
        fscanf(file, "%d", &firstValues[i]); //read the 1st value as integer
        fscanf(file, "%d", &secondValues[i]); //read the 2nd value as integer
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS; ++i)
        printf("%s %d %d\n", names[i], firstValues[i], secondValues[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**PS.** I'd recommend using one array and store a `struct` in it, which encapsulates the three values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRINGS (10)
#define MAX_STRING_LEN (100)

typedef struct
{
    char name[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int firstValue;
    int secondValue;
} ValuesType;

int main()
{
    ValuesType dataArray[MAX_STRINGS] = { 0 };

    FILE* file = fopen("text.txt", "r"); // check if open was successful!

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS; ++i)
    {
        if (!fscanf(file, "%s", dataArray[i].name)) //read the name as string
            break;
        fscanf(file, "%d", &dataArray[i].firstValue); //read the 1st value as integer
        fscanf(file, "%d", &dataArray[i].secondValue); //read the 2nd value as integer
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d\n", dataArray[i].name, dataArray[i].firstValue, dataArray[i].secondValue);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before going into parsing the strings there is a critical mistake in the code. You haven't written the strings into the array correctly.

You created an array of (char *) pointers with size 100, so basically you have 100 pointers to strings but no memory allocated for the strings.
Then you pointed each pointer in that array to the array 'line'.
So basically after the first while loop, the strings array looks like that:

```
[0] "Andy 4 14"
[1] "Andy 4 14"
[2] "Andy 4 14"
[3] "Andy 4 14"
[4] (trash)
[5] (trash)
...
```

Thats because they all point to the line array which at the end of the loop contains the last line in the file which is "Andy 4 14".

What you want to do here is either dynamically allocate space for each string with malloc(3), or declare your strings array like that, allocating memory on the stack:

```
char strings[100][100];
```

Then use fgets to write into the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRINGS (100)
#define MAX_STRING_LEN (100)

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    char strings[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN] = { 0 };
    FILE *file = NULL;

    file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (NULL == file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file.");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS; i++) {
        if (NULL == fgets(strings[i], MAX_STRING_LEN, file)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS; i++) {
        printf("%s", strings[i]);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```